# In an engineering/optimisation context, does set $E$ have any special significance?

Tags: terminology, convex-optimization

I am reading a paper about optimsation and the description, while mostly being a very good description, makes reference to some variables being in some set $E$.  For example, it states that parameter $x\in E^n$.  However it does not mention the significance of $E$ or why it did not say $\mathbb{R}$ instead.  I suppose the algorithm in discussion doesn't only apply to reals, but also complex numbers, etc.  I am wondering though, whether the description merely means $E$ to mean, "some set," or if they mean something more specific.  For example it could mean E to stand for "enumerated," which I guess would mean they only mean to refer to "computer-representable" numbers, which I guess technically is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  I am not familiar with any special significance of the letter $E$ in engineering as applied to sets, so I wanted to make sure by asking.

Here is the description from the paper:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULt6J.png

Can anyone please give me their best interpretation of $E$ here? Thanks.

Comment: I do not think $E$ is a set. Probably $E^n$ is meant to stand for Euclidean $n$-space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E^n$ is often used to denote *$n$-dimensional [Euclidean space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space)*, which is the same as $\mathbb R^n$. The symbol $E$ is often used to emphasize that the author is endowing $\mathbb R^n$ with the Euclidean inner product, or dot product, to make it into a Hilbert space. I've also seen it used to emphasize that $\mathbb R^n$ is being given a manifold structure.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of Euclidean for some reason. I usually see Euclidean space written $\mathbb{R}^n$, so it didn't occur to me!  But your explanation makes perfect sense.  In fact, in optimisation, distance is very important, so it would make sense that Euclidean properties should be defined.